# Optimizing code for sequence A064604

Tags: python, programming-challenge, mathematics, complexity

I am implementing [A064604 - OEIS](https://oeis.org/A064604) for positive integers up to 10 billion.

I am finding the divisors in \$O(\sqrt N)\$. So, the overall time complexity of running the formula right now is \$O(N\sqrt N)\$. How do I improve on this?

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tYxRkqp2)

```
import math

def factors(n):    
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, 
                ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))

def sigma_4(n):
    l = factors(n)
    ans=0
    for factor in l:
        ans += (pow(factor,4))
    return ans

n=int(raw_input())
ans=0
for i in xrange(1,n+1):
    ans+=sigma_4(i)
print ans
```

Comment: What are you going to use these numbers for? Is this for a programming challenge?

Comment: It is a sort of a subproblem of a programming challenge

Comment: Can you point us at the challenge? I had a quick look but the closest match I found was [Project Euler problem 401](http://projecteuler.net/problem=401), which is based on sums of sigma2.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very naive bruteforce algorithm.  To optimize this sort of calculation you can usually "turn it around" by doing something like: for each possible divisor, computing the number of times it'll feature as a contributor and adding them up.  And if you can get it to work by just iterating over primes, it'll be even better/faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for sigma_4

```
def sigma_4(n):
    return sum([i**4 for i in factors(n)])
```